# What happened to \luatextextdir?

Tags: luatex, arabic, updating, right-to-left

As of today, the command `\luatextextdir` does no longer seem to work. I employ the command in order to be able to typeset Arabic. To that end I created the following commands:

```
\newcommand{\arabtext}[1]       % Arabic inside LTR
    {\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\arabnr}[1]         % for numbers inside Arabic text
    {\bgroup\luatextextdir TLT #1\egroup}
\newenvironment{arabpar}            % Arabic paragraph
    {\luatextextdir TRT\luatexpardir TRT\arabicfont}{}
```

As of today, however, I get the otherwise well-known "Undefined control sequence" - error.

I just updated all the packages to the newest version using the TeX Live Utility.

Comment: `luatex` prefix was removed in recent LaTeX release, try just `\textdir`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The 'proper' (internal) name of the primitive has always been `\textdir`, but for various reasons it used to be 'activated' as `\luatextextdir` in LuaLaTeX. The LaTeX team have recently revised this approach and all primitives now have their 'natural' names in LuaLaTeX. Thus you should either update your code or add

```
\directlua{
  tex.enableprimitives("luatex",tex.extraprimitives("luatex"))
}
```

to your preamble.

(`\textdir` comes from Omega so is currently in a list called `omega`. At some stage in the near future it will be moved to a list called `luatex`, so `tex.extraprimitives("omega", "luatex")` is slightly more future-proof. However, I'd strongly advise revising your code to drop the prefix entirely.)

Comment: The team have contacted most package authors to have these names changed, but obviously that's not possible for direct end-user usage.

Comment: Did you contact Arthur regarding luabidi? It still uses \luatextextdir etc.