# arabluatex - undefined control sequence

Tags: arabic

I have a simple test document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,luatextra}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Droid Arabic Naskh}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\begin{document}
hello \arb{EaAlam}
\end{document}
```

Which fails with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\arb code ...@tempa \al@mode@voc \bgroup \textdir  TRT\arabicfont      \luadirect 
 l.6 hello \arb{EaAlam}
```

I can see from the log that it finds arabluatex.sty:

```
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/arabluatex/arabluatex.sty
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
```

I don't know where to look to fix this. Any suggestions would be much  appreciated.

(I'm running on FreeBSD 10.3 and manually installed the arabluatex package.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I had to change the font name, but with an up-to-date TeX distribution I get no error.

Comment: as with egreg, I got no error after changing the font but you should probably not load `luatextra` these days it is just a thin wrapper loading several unneeded packages including fixltx2e which generates the warning `Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015`

Comment: I have same error  with `texlive 2015` on windows, when changed to `texlive 2016` the error disappear.

Comment: I just installed the Droid Arabic Naskh font from Parabola Linux repos. Then I didn't get any error with your mwe, either with `texlive 2015` and `arabluatex 1.2` or with `texlive 2016` and `arabluatex 1.3`. I suspect something is wrong in your installation. Maybe a full `.log` file with `\listfiles` would help.

Comment: Another quick comment on your mwe (which has nothing to do with your issue): what you put inside `\arb{}` is Buckwalter notation; it should be `ArabTeX` instead, like so: Hello \arb{`Alam}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\textdir` is the culprit: about one year ago the prefix `luatex` was removed from the primitives `\luatexXYZ` and the like.  Actually, the names of such internal primitives have always been *without* the prefix, but they were 'activated' *with* the 'luatex' prefix. See [What happened to \luatextextdir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273301) for more information.

The solution is either to install the latest texlive 2016 on your system or to replace every occurrence of `\textdir` with `\luatextextdir` in `arabluatex.sty`.  But this is actually more a workaround than a solution.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their info. Installing texlive 2016 fixed the problem.

Comment: Off-topic question: may I know how can I underline an Arabic text inside `txarab` environment since `\underline` typesets the Arabic words in a wrong way?

Comment: @Diaa You can use the `ulem` package.  Just load it, and you may say for example: `\txarab{دَخَلَ \uline{مُبتَسِمًا}}`.  That said, the development version of `arabluatex` (see: https://gitlab.com/ralessi/arabluatex) has more refinements and also uses `ulem` internally.  I should be out soon.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out after asking this question on the main site.