# Revision on "Chinese, Russian and English (and Arabic, and Thai, if possible) in LuaLaTeX"

Tags: luatex, languages

Following up on [THE ACCEPTED ANSWER](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250288/chinese-russian-and-english-and-arabic-and-thai-if-possible-in-lualatex) to a question I posted a year ago, I wanted it to be revised, as I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and texlive from 2013 to 2015, and there are parts of the code that do not work now...

In particular, those parts regarding Arabic and Hebrew.

```
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Linux Libertine O} 
\newcommand{\texthebrew}[1]{%
    \bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\hebrewfont #1\egroup%
}


\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic]{Droid Arabic Naskh} % free with Debian GNU/Linux
\newcommand{\textarabic}[1]{%
    \bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup%
}
```

It seems like the current LTS Ubuntu release does not carry the font "Droid Arabic Naskh" so I am getting a "font not found" error; is there another font that should be use instead, or a way to get this font back?

Besides I get the following 2 errors:

> ! Undefined control sequence. \textarabic #1->\bgroup \luatextextdir
>   TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup l.622 \end{frame}
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \texthebrew #1->\bgroup \luatextextdir
>   TRT\hebrewfont #1\egroup l.622 \end{frame}

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I solved it! The use of \luatextextdir was the main problem.

1- Download Droid Arabic Naskh from [here](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/droid-arabic-naskh)

2- Install it with:

```
sudo gnome-font-viewer DroidArabicNaskh/DroidNaskh-Regular.ttf
sudo gnome-font-viewer DroidArabicNaskh/DroidNaskh-Bold.ttf
```

3- Change \luatextextdir with \textdir (as indicated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273301/what-happened-to-luatextextdir))